# Why does my PHP header('Location:...') call disregard the HTTP GET request?

Tags: php, http-headers

I have 3 files, *account.php*, *index.php*, and *browser.php*.

Upon a successful login *account.php* calls the following function:

```
header('Location: index.php?m='.base64_encode('Signed in'));
```

To which *index.php* calls:

```
header('Location: ./browser.php?m='.$_GET['m']);
```

And *browser.php* displays:

```
if(isset($_GET['m']))
    echo '<h3 style="color:green">'.base64_decode($_GET['m']).'</h3>';
```

The problem is the *header('Location:...')* call from *index.php* to *browser.php* drops anything after the *'?'*. Everytime the url just displays *browser.php*

What is going on?

---

**[EDIT]**

Well the problem was fixed, by some horrible if else logic in the index.php. **Doing the following does not work (will always run the latest header)**:

```
if(isset($_GET['m']))
    header('Location: browser.php?m='.$_GET['m']);
if(isset($_GET['e']))
    header('Location: browser.php?e='.$_GET['e']);
header('Location: browser.php');
```

I had to restructure it like so:

```
if(isset($_GET['m']))
    header('Location: browser.php?m='.$_GET['m']);
else if(isset($_GET['e']))
    header('Location: browser.php?e='.$_GET['e']);
else
    header('Location: browser.php');
```

But frankly this is all irrelevant, I should be using $_SESSION to preserve variables on redirects. Thanks everyone!

Comment: why not use sessions instead? passing login information via urls seems like a very bad idea

Comment: `header('Location: index.php?m='.base64_encode( '<script>alert("I just hacked you.");</script>)' ));`  Use sessions for this stuff, please.

Comment: always put `exit;` after redirecting with `header`

Comment: Answers are posted in the answers section, otherwise you have a blog instead of a question. You can mark your own answer as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Why do you use `base64_encode`, not `urlencode`?

2) `Location` header should be a complete url, including the protocol and server name (if I recall correctly).

3) See knittl's comment.

Comment: Marking you as solved as you pointed me to knittl's comment which would be the "answer" to what I am trying to achieve. Problem was in my if else logic.

Answer (score 2):

Why so complex structure? Why not to redirect from account directly to the browser?

Despite of the fact that browsers being extremely tolerant to the url syntax, it should be fully qualified url, beginning from http://. I doubt that `./` can be cause but why don't you make it just browser.php?

Anyway, you have to **debug** your code to spot the actual problem.

First of all you have to watch actual HTTP requests being sent. Firebug or LiveHTTPHeaders Firefox addons can do it.

To print out all location strings is absolutely necessary. Just substitute in turns all header() functions with echo() and see what actual header your code is about to send

Answer (score 0):

The code you are showing is faultless and should work. The problem must be elsewhere. Can you check the headers using Live HTTP Headers, Firebug or similiar and see what is happening? I think your problem is elsewhere.

**edit**: Other answers mention that relative urls are not standards-complient. This is true, but while RFCs forbid them, they do work (although I would not write ./browser.php but simply browser.php).